# hibernate jpa - join columns which are unrelated but linked with another column

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables which have a relationship like

```
usgroupTable(id, genericid)
genericTable(id, name)
```

General relationship is: `genericid` field of `usgroupTable` will be linked with `id` of `genericTable`, and it works fine for me after maintaining proper relationship (`@OnetoMany` in `usgroupTable` & `@ManytoOne` in `genericTable`).

But what I need to do is join `genericid` of `usgroupTable` with `name` field of `genericTable` without changing the relationship.

Basically, it's not related but I need it to join for a purpose. My domain class is big hence I have only shown relevant fields.

Please let me know whether this is possible using jpa ? If so how to do it?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the 'without changing the relationship' part. Are you simply asking how to establish a one-to-many association based on some other column than the parent's primary key?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPQL. For example, using your entites:

```
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
...
    Query query =em.createQuery("select t from UsgroupTable t join GenericTable p on t.genericid=p.name");
```

Result SQL will be something like this:

```
select t.*...<your fields> from UsgroupTable t inner join GenericTable on t.genericid=p.name
```